# Enable Session globally in .net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Is there a way to enable the session globally (ie in the web.config) rather than on each method in a web service?

We have a huge (wcf) webservice with many many methods and I would rather not have to go in and add the attribute to every method.....

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google will tell you that you need to specify attributes on ServiceContract and not at method level.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ICalculatorSession
```

Moreover WCF sessions are represented as service instances (as CLR objects) and the states are part of each service instance. The sessions are initiated by the calling WCF client. WCF relies on special context to provide correlation for the sessions: sessionful channels, secure conversations, reliable-messaging, etc.

WCF sessions are not same as ASP.NET Session. To use ASP.NET session you would need to enable ASP.NET compatibility mode on the WCF service.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorSession
```

Useful links:

[Using Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a better way. I am now using MemoryCache which is part of System.Runtime.Caching

Comment: Not sure what makes you think that cache and session are same thing. Are you planning to share same data across Services and OperationContracts

Comment: I may have been a little unclear..... I needed caching but could not access the current context, I thought enabling session would give me access to the current context. However the above method seems to be a better option.